# Создание HashMap из List с использованием valueMapper

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Есть метод, которому в параметре передается список строк (`List<String>`), из этого списка мне необходимо составить `Map<String,Long>`, где ключом(key) будет соответственно строка из списка, а значение(value) равно 1, но если такой ключ уже присутствует т.е. в списке имеются одинаковые строки, то инкрементировать значение на единицу

Для списка строк "HelloJava", "World", "HelloJava" map должен выглядеть: {HelloJava=2, World=1}

Вот мой метод:

```
    public void myMethod(List<String> lines) {
    HashMap<String, Long> myMap = lines.stream()
                                       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(???));
}
```

знаю, что еще можно сделать через `Collectors.toMap(???)`, но не знаю, что написать в параметрах коллектора

Comment: lines.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), v -> 1L, Long::sum))

Comment: @Serodv , спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map<String, Long> myMap = lines.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```